# No JavaScript bugs according to Chrome's JavaScript console, yet my page isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't figure out what seems to be the matter here. As a test, my code is supposed to write something to the top of the page. And there's supposed to be a table under that. All that is happening, however, is a blank page is displaying with the proper background color.

Anything here look funny to you?

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Simple encrypt/decrypt</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        body 
        {
            background-color: #A9F5F2;
        }
        #divuno
        {
            height: 700px;
            width: 100%;
        }

    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function encrypt(thisString)
        {
            retString = "";
            /* Make retString a string of the bit representations of 
               the ASCII values of its thisCharacters in order.
            */
            for (i = 0, j = thisString.length; i < j; i++) 
            { 
                bits = thisString.thisCharCodeAt(i).toString(2);
                retString += new Array(8-bits.length+1).join('0') + bits;
            }
            /* Compress retString by taking each substring of 3, 4, ..., 9 
               consecutive 1's or 0's and it by the number of such consecutive
               thisCharacters followed by the thisCharacter. 
               EXAMPLES:
                    "10101000010111" --> "10101401031"
                    "001100011111111111111" --> "0011319151"
            */
            retString = retString.replace(/([01])\1{2,8}/g, function($0, $1) { return ($0.length + $1);});

            return retString;
        } 

        function decrypt(thisString) 
        {
            thisString.trim();
            var result = "", thisChar = "";
            for (var i = 0, j = thisString.length(); i < j; ++i) 
            {
                thisChar = thisString.thisCharAt(i);
                console.log(thisChar - '0');
                if (thisChar > 1) 
                    result += new Array(+thisChar + 1).join(thisString.thisCharAt(++i));
                else 
                    result += thisChar;
            }
            if (!(result.length % 8))
            {
                alert ("Improper input; cannot decrypt");
                return;
            }
            for (var i = 0, j = result.length; i < j; i += 8)
            {
                result = "";
                result += parseInt(thisString.substr(i,8), 2);
            }
            return result;
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(encrypt("Yo, dawg, I heard you like functions"));
    </script>

    <div id="divuno">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Type in or paste text below, then click Encrypt or Decrypt</td>
                <td><input type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've typed `thisCharCodeAt` instead of `charCodeAt`. You also have `</script>` instead of `</style>`, causing the rest of the document to be treated as a stylesheet.